# How to check the physical status of an ethernet port in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

How can I check the TX/RX power on a windows server ? I can check this connection switch side (show transceiver ...) but I can't check Windows side. The windows driver (intel or mellanox) has no info about tx/rx power

How can I check  ? with a tool ?

Thanks

Comment: anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Contol Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> click on Network and Sharing Center on the left sidebar.

Right click on your network device -> Properties -> Networking tab -> Configure -> Adanvced

Check each option for the Ethernet card you have. It might be Flow Control property.

Comment: HiThanks for your answer but there are no option for the power level (TX/RX) in the driver and no tool with this card

Comment: What is the card name?